# How can I change the color of my statusline depending on whether the current buffer has been modified?

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim and I want to set the color for a portion of my statusline, depending on whether the buffer has been modified or not. I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
set statusline=%{&modified=='nomodified'?'%#User1#':'%#User2#'}
" restore normal highlight
set statusline+=\ %*
```

And in my colorscheme, I have the following:

```
 hi User1 gui=NONE guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF
 hi User2 gui=NONE guifg=#000000 guibg=#FF0000
```

This only adds the messages %#User1# and %#User2# in my statusline, depending on whether the current buffer has been modified or not; it does not change the color of the statusline.

Is there a way to change the color of the statusline with a simple if/else statement, like the one I described above?

Comment: As a newcomer, you certainly have more pressing things to do than customising your status line. Vim's `[+]` is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/romainl/58245df413641497a02ffc06fd1f4747):

```
highlight IsModified    ctermbg=red
highlight IsNotModified ctermbg=green
set statusline+=%#IsModified#%{&mod?'[THIS BUFFER IS MODIFIED!!!]':''}%*
set statusline+=%#IsNotModified#%{&mod?'':'[THIS BUFFER IS PRISTINE!!!]'}%*
```

Comment: That's clever. Thank you.